# .htaccess xml file block for 127.0.0.1

Tags: .htaccess

I want to protect a file from user but let my javascript get it !
So i use a .htaccess to protect like this

```
# Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working
RewriteBase /
<Files "bd.xml">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

But my xml query script return me this :

```
 TypeError: xml is null
```

(The probleme come from the .htacces, if i remove it all is good)

So i Require your help !
Event if it's not with the .htacces ! All i need to do is to avoid user to see the xml document but allow my script to get it !

Comment: Is the JavaScript executing on 127.0.0.1, or is bd.xml being retrieved by a client browser which has a different IP address?

Comment: There is no difference between a request from the user and a request from JS code in the user's browser.  You can't do that.

Comment: So how can i Protect my xml file ?